# Curvature estimate for minimal surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curvature, quasiconformal, minimal-surfaces

I am a bit confused about Theorem 2.16 in the book ["A Course in Minimal Surfaces"](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-121) by Colding and Minicozzi. The authors write that Theorem 2.16 was proved in [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1b7x7tv.9?refreqid=excelsior%3Ad83238340e13a211195956221927fefe&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) paper by Schoen and Simon in the more general setting of surfaces with quasiconformal Gauss map.

I looked at the paper of Schoen and Simon, but they prove a Holder estimate for the Gauss map. How can one get the curvature estimate in Colding-Minicozzi's book from that Holder estimate?

Any help will be very much apreciated!

This is the statement of Theorem 2.16.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**EDIT**

> **Theorem 2.16** : Let $0 \in \Sigma \subset B_{r_0} = B_{r_0}(0) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be an embedded simply connected minimal surface with $\partial \Sigma \subset \partial B_{r_0}$. If $\mu > 0$ and either 
>   \begin{equation}(i)\qquad Area(\Sigma) \le \mu r_0^2 \end{equation}
>   or
>   \begin{equation} (ii) \qquad \int_{\Sigma}|A|^2 \le \mu, \end{equation}
>   then for the connected component $\Sigma'$ of $B_{\frac{r_0}{2}} \cap \Sigma$ with $0 \in \Sigma'$ we have
>   \begin{equation}(\star) \qquad \sup_{\Sigma'}|A|^2 \le C r_0^{-2} \end{equation}
>   for some $C = C(\mu)$.

**I know that one cannot expect such a strong estimate for a general surface with quasiconformal Gauss map.** For instance consider a cylinder $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$. It has quasiconformal Gauss map because it has bounded (actually constant) mean curvature. Moreover it has linear area growth and thus in particular it satisfies $(i)$ for large $r_0$. But it does not satisfy $(\star)$.

On the other hand from the paper of Schoen and Simon I would expect to derive a pointwise curvature estimate, but I don't know how.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**SECOND EDIT**:

$A$ denotes the second fundamental form.

Comment: Could you state Theorem 2.16 in your question?

Comment: @DeaneYang Thanks for your comment. I just edited the question, including the statement of Thm 2.16 with a remark.

Comment: Sorry. One more quibble. You should say what $A$ is. Looks like it's the second fundamental form.

Comment: I believe a proof of the statement with assumption (ii) can be found in a paper by Schoen, Simon, and Yau titled Curvature estimates for minimal hypersurfaces.

Comment: ok! Thanks a lot!! Do you know if one can get any pointwise curvature estimate for a general quasiconformal surface assuming condition (i)? (As I wrote above, I don't expect such a strong estimate as in the statement of THM 2.16, because of the counterexample given by the cylinder. But maybe something weaker? Like $|A| \in L^{\infty}(\Sigma)$?

Comment: You are right, $A$ is the second fundamental form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theorem 2.16 (for embedded minimal disks) is implicit in Schoen-Simon.  There are two steps.  The first is that some area (or total curvature) bound on an extrinsic ball implies small total curvature on a sub-ball.  This is the key point and it is this that is generalized to intrinsic balls here.

Schoen and Simon show that the area bound implies small total curvature on a sub-ball even for surfaces with quasi-conformal Gauss maps.  The argument that gives this also implies a Holder estimate on the Gauss map.

The second part, which is true for minimal surfaces but not necessarily more generally, is that small total curvature implies a point-wise estimate.  There are many ways to see this.  The simplest is via the Choi-Schoen estimate.  One could also see it from Schoen-Simon-Yau in this case since one also has area bounds.